# Chat client sending some weird characters

Tags: c#, sockets

So I am creating a socket based web chat using C#. This is a school project.
It is basic server-client chat -> client sends message to server, server "broadcast" == sends message to all connected clients.

However if I connect two clients, and send message from one to another I only get something like:

▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯

When I press "SEND" again (with the same message), it turns out good.

This is function for receiving.. I use it in Thread.

```
public void wait()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while (!shutdown)
        {
           // if (shutdown) break;
            try
            {
                int bytesRec = senderSocket.Receive(bytes);

                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    output.Text += "\n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (scroll.VerticalOffset == scroll.ScrollableHeight)
                    {
                        scroll.ScrollToEnd();
                    }

                }));
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is for sending: (LCP is my own "protocole".. ignore this, it just adds one letter to string)

```
private void send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            LCP protocol = new LCP();
            string messg = user.Text + " pravi: " + message.Text ;
            string messag = protocol.CreateMessage(messg, "M");
            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messag);
            // Send the data through the socket.
            senderSocket.Send(msg);
           // int bytesRec = senderSocket.Receive(bytes);
            //output.Text += "\n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and this is how I handle things on server:

```
try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);


        while (true)
        {
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();
            data = null;
            users.Add(handler.RemoteEndPoint);
            socks.Add(handler);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                    LCP protocolParser = new LCP();
                    Dictionary<string, string> wholeMessage = protocolParser.ParseMessage(data);

                    if (wholeMessage["type"] == "$J")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPridružil se je " + wholeMessage["message"]);
                        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wholeMessage["message"] + " se je pridružil");

                        foreach (Socket edp in socks)
                        {
                            edp.Send(msg);
                            //handler.SendTo(msg,edp);


                        }

                    }
                    // Show the data on the console.
                    else if (wholeMessage["type"] == "$Q")
                    {
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
                        handler.Close();
                        socks.Remove(handler);

                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + wholeMessage["message"]);
                        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wholeMessage["message"]);

                       // Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        //{
                        foreach (Socket edp in socks)
                        {
                            edp.Send(msg);
                            //handler.SendTo(msg,edp);


                        }

                       // }));


                    }
                }
                //tvoja koda
            })
            ){IsBackground=true}.Start();
            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.


            // Echo the data back to the client.

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for including your code and what is actually going wrong. Given the large amount of code, have you been able to narrow the problem down at all?

Comment: Where do you get `▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯`, Is it on the client after it makes the round trip there and back or are you getting it in `Console.WriteLine("\n" + wholeMessage["message"]);` on the server?

Comment: Server write a blank line... So I am guessing on server too, -> because server is console and i guess console cant write rectangles

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you don't have any mechanism to ensure you've read all of the data that was sent, which could lead to your UTF8 decoding getting out of sync (something that could happen if the user's name or the message itself contain non-ASCII characters). That would cause the decoding errors you seem to be getting. Another issue is that you don't seem to be handling socket shutdown correctly, but that's a separate problem; i.e. would not cause the text errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this using TcpListener and TcpClient class.